# linebreak at exact position css woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I have a WooCommerce website on which

I have added a bit of custom CSS code.
I want a line break after the 1st "€" character.

Unfortunately, the class for taxes is called the same and

therefore a line break is also inserted at the "€" symbol for taxes ("MwSt.").

How can I get a line break only after the 1st € symbol.

The result should look like this:

```
13,90 €
(incl. 2.22 € MwSt.)
```

And not like this:

```
13,90 €
(incl. 2,22 € 
MwSt.)
```

In addition here are some screenshots:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBgHU.png)

[Chrome Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIhUA.png)

[CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zfrp.png)

[Screenshot cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppszj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The woo-commerce plugin has an option to put a space between price and currency, it can be found here:

**woo-commerce** << **Settings**

[image: wordpress user interface with option highlighted]

Comment: No, this will change both € symbols as well. I only want to change the first

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the span and get as specific as you can about it:

```
woocommerce-Price-amount.amount bdi span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol::after{
  content: '\A ';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Not an absolute guarantee that this is enough because there may be other instances which you don't want changed, but we don't have enough info to check.

Comment: This one works for the checkout page but not for the cart spage... in need the same for the cart page

Comment: Well, you'll have to show us what the code is - and please this time include it in your question as code not as a screen shot image, thanks.

Comment: There is no specific code. I only added your code an now it works in the checkout section. This is all additional code in wordpress ... i only can show you a screenshot from chrome inspector on the specific cart page (see "screenshot cart page") ... thank you so much for your time

Comment: Just for the future, you can always copy and paste the code rather than provide an image. It makes it much easier for us to help. What do you mean by 'there is no specific code'? You have said that my code doesn't work on the cart page, so where is the snippet from the cart page where you want to add a newline? It sounds like we'll have to use a different selector but I can't work that out without seeing the relevant bit of the cart page.

Comment: i posted your code in the "additional css" section in my theme ... i thought it is possible to see how the cart page can be addressed by using the chrome inspector. this is not possible? have you seen the screenshot? thx again

Comment: You don't seem to have expanded the relevant elements in the screenshot for the cart page. And PLEASE heed the request to post code not to post images - this isn't the only reason for asking for this but it is one of them!

Comment: Okay, I will post the code.
However, I have now seen that the display changes depending on the number of items in the shopping cart.

If there is only one item in the basket, the total and tax are displayed on one line. If there is more than one item in the basket, the total and tax is displayed on 2 lines. Regardless of whether you are in the shopping basket or checkout.

I think this problem can't be solved with CSS, can it?